# How to recover a resized btrfs lvm partition

Tags: recover, btrfs

I tried shrinking a `btrfs lvm` partition to make room for another new partition. I've used `fdisk`. I deleted and recreated the btrfs partition. To my despair, the btrfs partition is now typeless. I tried

```
$ sudo btrfs restore /dev/sda6 /mnt/sda6/
No valid Btrfs found on /dev/sda6
Could not open root, trying backup super
No valid Btrfs found on /dev/sda6
Could not open root, trying backup super
No valid Btrfs found on /dev/sda6
Could not open root, trying backup super

$ sudo btrfs rescue chunk-recover /dev/sda6
read super block error
recover prepare error
Chunk tree recovery failed

$ sudo btrfs rescue super-recover /dev/sda6
No valid Btrfs found on /dev/sda6
Usage or syntax errors
```

Answer (score -1):

With parted I first decreased the size of the previous partition. `/dev/sda5` and now I was able to `mkpart` with the old start sector of the deleted partition. voila! got back the deleted partition with all files intact.